# Graphql response not coming from Apollo client query

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, express-graphql

in my local http://localhost:3000/graphql query is working like below...
[image]

but when I am querying through apollo client its response coming empty

```
import {InMemoryCache, gql, ApolloClient, HttpLink} from 'apollo-boost';
const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/graphql',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  }),
  },
});

client
  .query({
    query: gql`
      {
        brands {
          _id
        }
      }
    `,
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => {
    // its coming in this section
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Don't know what I am missing. Any help is appreciated Thanks !!!

**below are the screenshots, when I am trying to query from frontend side**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: we would like to see the errors on your console

Comment: @Abdelhedihlel updated with error screenshot

Comment: raw response? length 246?

Comment: @xadm didnt get it

Comment: compare request body (with playground) ... and bad response body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved by adding in app.js

```
global.XMLHttpRequest = global.originalXMLHttpRequest || global.XMLHttpRequest;
global.FormData = global.originalFormData || global.FormData;

if (window.FETCH_SUPPORT) {
  window.FETCH_SUPPORT.blob = false;
} else {
  global.Blob = global.originalBlob || global.Blob;
  global.FileReader = global.originalFileReader || global.FileReader;
}
```

reference: https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/382#issuecomment-544226529

Comment: add `react-native` tag next time